# Connect Power BI Desktop to insightly

Tags: powerbi, insightly

It doesn't seem possible to connect Power BI Desktop to Insightly although there's a content pack for Power BI Service.
Is there a workaround, if we need to build a data model and/or add calculated measures? E.g. use the content pack for the service and then connect Desktop to Power BI service?

Or any better suggestion? Thank you for helping with this!

Answer (score 1):

You could always connect by finding the URL being passed in the Power BI service and use that as a Web data source from Power BI desktop. That way you'd be able to create your data model.

There are additional details here which guide you through the insightly portal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-connect-to-insightly

There is a section within the above named "Finding Parameters" here it goes through how you can access the insightly portal. Additionally there is information around how to access the insightly API. Please note there is daily limit on the number of calls to this API.

> select User Settings from the Insightly profile menu and scroll down.
>   This string of characters will be used to connect your data to Power BI.

Insightly API documentation can be found here:

https://api.insight.ly/v2.2/Help#!/Overview/Introduction#ratelimit

An example of an API call using the Power BI Web data source is as follows:

```
https://api.insight.ly/v2.2/Contacts
```

Using the key which can be found under the "Finding Parameters" tab you're able to populate the below:

[image]

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Better response :)